# Measure Frequency of a square wave via edge detection GPIO

Tags: timer, embedded, stm32, interrupt, gpio

I am doing embedded c programming, and I am out of timer peripherals to perform an input-capture and calculate the frequency of an incoming signal.
The signal is a square wave of 30-70 Hz. I need to accurately measure the frequency.

I have one GPIO pin available, and I was thinking, if I setup an external interrupt on the rising edge and find the time difference between(through HAL_Get_Tick()) the two consecutive interrupts interrupts, I could get the frequency, right?

Is this a good idea? If yes, what do I need to keep in mind?
If this is not a good idea, could anyone please help me with some ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see why that would not work, although I don't know how accurate it would be. If you had another timer already running at higher precision (e.g. once per microsecond), that might be better if you could "borrow" that. Why not just try it and see?

Comment: @pmacfarlane could you please elaborate a little more, as to how this method would work logically? would I have to change the Capture-Compare registers dynamically?

Comment: I just meant that if you already have another timer that ticks faster than 1 KHz you could read its counter, rather than reading the sysTick value. I'm not suggesting you modify anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your tick frequency is likely too low for any reasonable accuracy.  Consider that. How many ticks will you get in 1/70 seconds? Just 14 at 1ms tick interval, worse than 7% accuracy.

You would do better perhaps to read the SYSCLK counter register directly rather than the tick count, which is the SYSCLK reload interval count. The high-resolution time being:

```
tick_count * sysclk_reload + sysclk_count
```

bearing in mind the calculation is non-atomic and may be interrupted by a SYSTICK modifying the `tick_count`.

Pseudocode :

```
do
{
    tick_count = HAL_Get_Tick() ;
    highres_time = tick_count * sysclk_reload + SYSTICK_COUNT_REGISTER ;
} while( tick_count != HAL_Get_Tick() ) b
```

The resolution of `highres_time` is then the `SystemCoreClock` frequency - MHz rather than the typically 1KHz system tick.

You need to also consider the impact of any higher priority interrupts that may pre-empt the frequency measurement. For minimal timing jitter the GPIO EXTI interrupt needs to be the highest priority.

While at the low frequency range you specify it is probably feasible to measure the time of a single cycle with sufficient accuracy, it is probably not generally applicable.  For high frequencies, line conditions are likely to be such that the point at which the GPIO switches is insufficiently deterministic and the measurement will be noisy.  That can be dealt with with a low-pass filter (DSP) or a moving average.

An alternative method is to *count* the edges over a period of time, determine the frequency by count/time where the longer the time period, the more precise the measurement.  You could even have a fixed minimal precision by requiring a minimum number of counts.  For example 1000 counts will give 0.1% precision.  To advise specifically, you would need to quantify the precision required, and also the required update frequency, since at 30Hz, it will take >33 seconds to obtain a frequency update which will necessarily be an average over that period, so the *bandwidth* (rate at which the frequency may vary) of your system is another consideration.

So for example, given an EXTI handler incrementing a counter `ext_edge_count` say:

```c
#define MIN_UPDATE_COUNT  100u     // 1% precision
#define MINIMUM_UPDATE_MS 1000u    // Update interval no less than 1 second.
#define TICK_RATE 1000u            // Normal HAL tick rate

uint32_t getExtFreq()
{
    static uint32_t previous_count = 0 ;
    static uint32_t previous_time = HAL_Get_Tick() ;
    static uint32_t frequency = 0 ;

    uint32_t count = ext_edge_count ;
    uint32_t now = HAL_Get_Tick() ;

    uint32_t counts = count - previous_count ;
    uint32_t interval = now - previous_time ;

    // If sufficient interval and counts acquired...
    if(  counts >= MIN_UPDATE_COUNT &&
         interval >= MINIMUM_UPDATE_MS )
    { 
        // Update frequency (round to nearest integer Hz)
        frequency = ((counts * TICK_RATE) + (interval / 2)) / interval
    }

    return frequency ;
}
```

That will yield a frequency in Hz with a new value update every second or every 100 counts whichever is longer.  At 30-70Hz, the mimimum count will win.  I have assumed a tick interval of 1ms (STM32 HAL normal). You can eek-out a little more precision, say tenths of a Hz by `counts * TICK_RATE * 10`, but for *accuracy* you would have to increase the minimum count or use a higher resolution clock.

Also you might redesign your system to make better use of available timers. For example, a single hardware timer could be used to implement many software timers (as an RTOS would provide).

While it is possible your application requires all these independent hardware timers, most STM32 parts have a relatively large number, and in my experience *"running out of timers"* is often a design issue rather than an application constraint.